# Display one row of list in a subsites main page (sp 2013 on office 365 host)

Tags: 2013, list, web-part, sub-site

Im trying to find a way to display information from one row in a list in a subsite

the senerio is that we write many proposals for work and we have one site that keeps information to all proposals and sub-sites for each individual proposal

I would like to display each individuals proposals entry in the main page of that sub-site but It doesn't seem like there is a good out of the box way to do this

I have full access to the site so I can use Sharepoint Designer but i'm just not sure how to start (SharePoint is new to me)

(bonus points if your answer allows me to format the text a little :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content Query Web Part will display content from a list in a parent site.  You can filter it using a field on the page.  You will need to create a page layout that includes a field you can use to filter by - this will be using SPD.  You will then need to create a page using that page layout for each subsite and add the correct filter value to each one.  You can either add the CQWP to the page layout or add it as a web part to each page.

You will then filter the CQWP using PageFieldValue: FieldName.

That said, it seems to me that if you have a sub-site for each proposal then you may actually be better creating a roll-up at the parent level and storing all the proposal details in the sub-site?

Comment: I thought about that but things from other groups go into the "master" as well and we need them to have permissions to that and the proposal sites get deleted after some time anyway

Comment: this might be lack of sleep on my part but I dont see content query in the list of webparts to insert on the page. Do you know if its available by default?

Comment: You do need the publishing infrastructure on to use CQWP which is a site collection level feature.  You would also need publishing for a page layout so it may be easier just to filter each CQWP in the settings?  How many of these proposals are there?

Comment: Could it be called "SharePoint server Publishing"  I dont see publishing infrastructure

Comment: If i try to activate Sharepoint Server Publishing I get the following error "Site
The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a dependency on a Site Collection scoped feature which has not been activated. Please activate the following feature before trying again: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
Web
The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on hidden Site scoped feature . Hidden features cannot be auto-activated across scopes. There may be one or more visible Site scoped features that auto-activate the dependent hidden feature.

Comment: Yep Publishing Infrastructure is the one you need - and as I said above this is at the site collection level.

Comment: First off thanks for all your help, I got it installed and working but It only seems to display a item from the list not the list entry itself, I was hoping to have it display the data in that row. any thoughts?

Comment: You will need to tweak the XSLT - there are a couple of posts on XSLT and CQWP on http://paylord.wordpress.com